# Iterate over a nested YAML Object Tree

Tags: python, ansible

I have a yaml object, which describes the structure of an organization:

```
orgas:
  - key: orga1
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: orga2
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: orga3
    description: "Description of orga"
    children:
      - key: sub-orga1
        description: "Description of sub-orga"
  - key: orga4
    description: "Description of orga"
    children:
      - key: sub-orga2
        description: "Description of sub-orga"
      - key: sub-orga3
        description: "Description of sub-orga"
        children:
          - key: sub-sub-orga1
            description: "Description of sub-sub-orga"
      - key: sub-orga4
        description: "Description of sub-orga"
        children:
          - key: sub-sub-orga2
            description: "Description of sub-sub-orga"
```

So basically, you have a list of orgas, each of which can have the attributes 'key', 'description', and 'children', which in turn can also contain more orgas.

I want to flatten and iterate the whole data structure to create these organizations in IPA as groups. In order to properly create the group elements, for each of the orgas I need to know:

- The key
- The description
- The key of parents (ordered)

The result should look something like this:

```
  - key: orga1
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: orga2
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: orga3
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: orga4
    description: "Description of orga"
  - key: sub-orga1
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["orga3"]
  - key: sub-orga2
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["orga4"]
  - key: sub-orga3
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["orga4"]
  - key: sub-orga4
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["orga4"]
  - key: sub-sub-orga1
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["sub-orga3", "orga4"]
  - key: sub-sub-orga2
    description: "Description of sub-orga"
    parents: ["sub-orga4", "orga4"]
```

Is this possible in Ansible?

Comment: could you show from your sample, the result you want? the key of parent ordered is not clear

Comment: @Frenchy added it

Comment: i think customfilter but you have a right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably easier to manage inside python directly with a custom filter. Here is an example I crafted which I believe meets your criteria but needs some hardening to be used in a wider range scenario.

The project structure is:

```
.
├── filter_plugins
│   └── orgas_utils.py
└── playbook.yml
```

Custom plugin in `filter_plugins/orgas_utils.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.orga_nodes_list=[]

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'orgas_flattened': self.orgas_flattened
        }

    def _process_orga(self, orga, direct_parent=None):
        if direct_parent:
            current_parents = [x for x in self.orga_nodes_list if x['key'] == direct_parent][0]['parents'] + [direct_parent]
        else:
            current_parents = []

        current_node= {
            'key': orga['key'],
            'description': orga['description'],
            'parents': current_parents
        }

        self.orga_nodes_list.append(current_node)

        for child in (orga['children'] if 'children' in orga.keys() else []):
            self._process_orga(child, direct_parent=current_node['key'])

    def orgas_flattened(self, orgas):
        for orga in orgas:
            self._process_orga(orga)
        return self.orga_nodes_list
```

And the test `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    orgas:
      - key: orga1
        description: "Description of orga"
      - key: orga2
        description: "Description of orga"
      - key: orga3
        description: "Description of orga"
        children:
          - key: sub-orga1
            description: "Description of sub-orga"
      - key: orga4
        description: "Description of orga"
        children:
          - key: sub-orga2
            description: "Description of sub-orga"
          - key: sub-orga3
            description: "Description of sub-orga"
            children:
              - key: sub-sub-orga1
                description: "Description of sub-sub-orga"
          - key: sub-orga4
            description: "Description of sub-orga"
            children:
              - key: sub-sub-orga2
                description: "Description of sub-sub-orga"

  tasks:
    - name: Show list processed by custom filter
      debug:
        msg: "{{ orgas | orgas_flattened }}"
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show list processed by custom filter] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "description": "Description of orga",
            "key": "orga1",
            "parents": []
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of orga",
            "key": "orga2",
            "parents": []
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of orga",
            "key": "orga3",
            "parents": []
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-orga1",
            "parents": [
                "orga3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of orga",
            "key": "orga4",
            "parents": []
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-orga2",
            "parents": [
                "orga4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-orga3",
            "parents": [
                "orga4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-sub-orga1",
            "parents": [
                "orga4",
                "sub-orga3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-orga4",
            "parents": [
                "orga4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Description of sub-sub-orga",
            "key": "sub-sub-orga2",
            "parents": [
                "orga4",
                "sub-orga4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```